# Understanding a java code

Tags: java

I'm new in java and I have to understand a huffman code. The program take the content of any file and encode it according to huffman coding schemes. There is this small part I don't understand in the code.
Its in the main file.
An array with a size of 256.
The comment says we will assume that all our characters will have code less than 256, for simplicity.
Why is it simple with 256? What happens if I increase or decrease the size of the array?
Also, for some sizes, I get an error out of bound.
Can someone explain why,
thanks

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String a = "test-short.txt";
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String content = new Scanner(new File(a)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        HuffmanCode newCode = new HuffmanCode();

        // we will assume that all our characters will have
        // code less than 256, for simplicity
        int[] charFreqs = new int[256];
        // read each character and record the frequencies
        for (char loop : content.toCharArray()){
            charFreqs[loop]++;
        }

        //Build tree
        //Parse the int array of frequencies to HuffmanTree
        HuffmanTree tree = newCode.createTree(charFreqs);

        // print out results
        System.out.println("Char\tFreq\tHUFF CODE");
        newCode.printResults(tree, new StringBuffer());
        newCode.findHeight(tree);
        printRwquiredResults(content, newCode.realcode, newCode.height, newCode.numberOfNode, newCode.printAverageDepth());
        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) );
    }

    public static void printRwquiredResults(String content, String compressedCode, int heightOfTree, int huffTreeTotalNode, float avrTreeDepth){
        int textFileLenght = (content.length()*3);
        int textFileCompressed = compressedCode.length();
        float compressionRatio = ((float) textFileLenght/textFileCompressed);
        System.out.println("Uncompressed file size: " + textFileLenght);
        System.out.println("Compressed file size: " + textFileCompressed);
        System.out.printf("Compression ratio: %.6f%n" , compressionRatio);
        System.out.println("Huffman tree height: " + heightOfTree);
        System.out.println("Huffman tree number of nodes: " + huffTreeTotalNode);
        System.out.printf("Huffman tree average depth: %.6f%n", avrTreeDepth);

    }

}
```

Comment: I'll leave this link here: http://www.ascii-code.com/. Look what it contains and how many rows that table has (first column). You'll may understand then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't see how this question could be useful to any future reader.

Comment: "any file": you won't know the character encoding used so just treat the file as a sequence of bytes and use the values 0-255 as the "alphabet" for the Huffman coding algorithm, avoiding character I/O and types altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java `char`s (which you get when you call `toCharArray()`) have a size of 16 bits, ranging (when interpreted as an unsigned type) [from 0 to 65535](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1):

> For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

This model is based on the original Unicode specification.

Theoretically, in order to represent all possible character frequencies, your array would require a size of 65536 (last index + 1).
However, most [charsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) (put simply: which code represents which character and vice versa) are built upon [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) which only uses 7 bits per character. Therefore, if you only use ASCII characters (e.g. digits, some special characters, whitespace and English [letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_(alphabet))), you can safely assume that all codes will be in a range from 0 to 255 (which is 8 bits, so one bit more than ASCII). And further: If you only use characters from the ASCII table, you can probably reduce your array size to 128 which should still be enough to hold all required frequencies ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) is a list of printable characters in ASCII):

```
int[] freq = new int[128]; // enough for ASCII characters
freq['A'] = 10;            // okay: ASCII character
freq['Ä'] = 10;            // not okay, will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
                           // as Ä is not an ASCII character

int[] freq = new int[256]; // enough for ASCII characters plus all
                           // 8-bit wide characters
freq['A'] = 10;            // okay: ASCII character
freq['Ä'] = 10;            // okay: Ä has the code 196 in UTF-8 which is not ASCII
                           // but our array is large enough to hold it
```